# Group by name and Include duplicate data in linq to xml c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm starting to learn asp.net and c# at work and I've been given a project to create and fix web pages in asp.net.

I am having trouble with one of the functions to display the data from xml to web page.

The intention of the code is to get the latest record(date and no time) at the top and the rest of records with same common name for same node will go below.

The problem is that at the moment if there are more than two nodes with same values and same dates it will split and treat like to different items and it will create two groups with two different top items.

Code:

```
var xd = XDocument.Parse(element.OuterXml);

if (xd != null)
{
    var results =
       (from el1 in xd.Descendants("Microbiology")
        from el2 in el1.Descendants("Test")
        orderby el2.Element("Date").Value descending
        //orderby el2.Element("Rubric").Value
        // I tried using distinct here but does not work.
        where el2.Element("Date").Value ==
              (el1.Descendants("Test").Where(
                  e => e.Element("ReadCode").Value ==
                      el2.Element("ReadCode").Value).First().Element("Date").Value) 
        select new Microbiology
        {
            Date = el2.Element("Date") != null ? el2.Element("Date").Value : "",
            ReadCode = el2.Element("ReadCode") != null
                           ? el2.Element("ReadCode").Value
                           : "",
            Rubric = el2.Element("Rubric") != null
                           ? el2.Element("Rubric").Value
                           : "",
            SubMicro = (from subMicroEl1 in xd.Descendants("Microbiology")
                        from subMicroEl2 in subMicroEl1.Descendants("Test")
                        orderby subMicroEl2.Element("Date").Value descending
                        orderby subMicroEl2.Element("Rubric").Value
                        where subMicroEl2.Element("Rubric").Value ==
                              el2.Element("Rubric").Value &&
                              subMicroEl2.Element("Date").Value !=
                              el2.Element("Date").Value
                        select new Microbiology
                        {
                            Date = subMicroEl2.Element("Date") != null
                                       ? subMicroEl2.Element("Date").Value
                                       : "",
                            ReadCode = subMicroEl2.Element("ReadCode") != null
                                       ? subMicroEl2.Element("ReadCode").Value
                                       : "",
                            Rubric = subMicroEl2.Element("Rubric") != null
                                       ? subMicroEl2.Element("Rubric").Value
                                       : "",
                        }).ToList<Microbiology>()
        });
```

XML:

```
<Microbiology>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value>123</Value>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
  <Value>123123</Value>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-10-23</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-30</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-30</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-30</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-30</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-07-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-05-12</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-05-12</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-05-12</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-05-12</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-03-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-03-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-03-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-03-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-01-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-01-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-01-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-01-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-01-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2008-01-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-11-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-11-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-11-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-11-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-10-08</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-10-08</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-10-08</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-10-08</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-10-08</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-10-08</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-08-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-08-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-06-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-06-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-06-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-06-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-05-04</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-05-04</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-05-04</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-05-04</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-01-26</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2007-01-26</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-09-29</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-09-29</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-31</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-31</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-31</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-31</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-16</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-16</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-16</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-08-16</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-06-02</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-06-02</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-06-02</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-06-02</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-05-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-05-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-05-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-05-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-01-17</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2006-01-17</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-11-22</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-11-22</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-10-18</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-10-18</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-10-18</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-10-18</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-09-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-09-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JRA.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus screening test</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-09-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-09-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-09-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-09-13</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-07-19</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-07-19</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-07-19</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-07-19</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-03-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-03-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-03-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-03-15</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2004-04-05</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2004-04-05</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2004-04-05</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2004-04-05</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2004-04-05</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J17.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample culture</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2004-04-05</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2003-10-06</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2003-10-06</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2003-01-20</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2003-01-20</Date>
        <ReadCode>4J15.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Sample: organism sensitivity</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2002-06-17</Date>
        <ReadCode>4I16.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Microscopy, culture and sensitivities</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2002-06-17</Date>
        <ReadCode>4I16.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Microscopy, culture and sensitivities</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>1998-04-02</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG3.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin ulcer swab taken</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2002-04-02</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG3.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin ulcer swab taken</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2002-01-09</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG6.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin swab culture positive</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-01-08</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG6.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin swab culture positive</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2005-12-05</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG3.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin ulcer swab taken</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-12-03</Date>
        <ReadCode>4I16.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Microscopy, culture and sensitivities</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-12-03</Date>
        <ReadCode>4I16.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Microscopy, culture and sensitivities</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-12-03</Date>
        <ReadCode>4I16.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Microscopy, culture and sensitivities</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-10-01</Date>
        <ReadCode>4I16.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Microscopy, culture and sensitivities</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-10-01</Date>
        <ReadCode>4I16.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Microscopy, culture and sensitivities</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-07-06</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG3.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin ulcer swab taken</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-06-12</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG3.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin ulcer swab taken</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-06-12</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG5.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin swab culture negative</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2001-05-22</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG6.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin swab culture positive</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2000-11-10</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG3.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin ulcer swab taken</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2000-09-19</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG3.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin ulcer swab taken</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2000-06-07</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JP..</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Methicillin resistant staphylococcus aureus positive</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Date>2000-01-31</Date>
        <ReadCode>4JG6.</ReadCode>
        <Rubric>Skin swab culture positive</Rubric>
        <Value/>
        <Units/>
    </Test>
</Microbiology>
```

I kind of understand what the code does, but I dont know how to modify it.

**Update**
What I need is to group them by Rubric or ReadCode and order them by date, even if dates are repeated I would just need one group and all elements inside with one with latest date situated at the top.

Any help would be appreciated.

Let me know if you need more info, I will keep checking the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also provide a piece of the XML that you are parsing?

Comment: @Ronald: There you have, its a bit long.

Comment: do I understand you correctly in that you wish to group the entities by common name and sort the groups by date descending?

Comment: @danijels: Yes, but I also want to display the repeated data (those entities with same name and date). Thanks.

Comment: @danijels: That code works fine when the dates are not duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding you, but is this what you look for?

```
var set = xd.Descendants("Microbiology");
var results = set.GroupBy(p => p.ReadCode).Select(g => new {Code = g.Key, Tests = g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)});
```

Hope that gets you closer

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultsRubric =     
    from el1 in xd.Descendants("Rubric")
    where el1.Value.Equals(rubricSearchValue)
    select el1.Parent;
```

OR

```
var resultsReadCode =     
    from el1 in xd.Descendants("ReadCode")
    where el1.Value.Equals(readCodeSearchValue)
    select el1.Parent;
```

OR

```
var resultsRubric =     
    from el1 in xd.Descendants("Test")
    where el1.FirstChild("Rubric").Value.Equals(rubricSearchValue) || el1.FirstChild("ReadCode").Value.Equals(readCodeSearchValue)
    select el1.Parent;
```

With all three of those code snippets you can simply use a variable to list which Rubric or ReadCode you are looking for and it will return a list of the Test elements that contain the needed codes.  From there you can go ahead and sort them in whichever way best appeals to you.  Hope this helped a little bit.

Comment: That is just a variable that would hold the value that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be something like this you want to do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        if (xd != null)
        {
            var tests = xd.Descendants("Test");

            var groupedResult = (from test in tests
                         select new Microbiology
                         {
                             Date = test.Element("Date").Value,
                             ReadCode = test.Element("ReadCode").Value,
                             Heading = test.Element("Rubric").Value
                         }).
                         OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).
                         GroupBy(y => y.ReadCode);
            var result = from item in groupedResult
                         select new Microbiology
                         {
                             ReadCode = item.First().ReadCode,
                             Date = item.First().Date,
                             Heading = item.First().Heading,
                             SubMicro = item.Skip(1).ToList()
                         };
            foreach (var res in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(res.Heading);
                foreach(var item in res.SubMicro)
                Console.WriteLine(item.ReadCode + " " + item.Date);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

What I do is the following: 1. Take all tests node. 2. Order them by date since that what you want. 3. Group them byt ReadCode so you get them grouped. 4. Select your result from the grouped result, and set SubMicro to the remaining list of elements (the skip(1) part, remove skip(1) if you want all the elements in the list.). Hope it helps.

Comment: you could probably optimize the code to make it shorter, but that's the first take on it.

Comment: Using linq I think it would make far more sense to just get the group that you want to work with from the start rather than reordering and regrouping a bunch of times. Simply throw a linq query that grabs the elements that have the ReadCode that is desired and then order by date, etc. etc.

Comment: See the new update, updated while you commented :). But I still think the groupedResult and result should be separated.